# Op-Amp variable pulse generator

Tags: operational-amplifier, multivibrator

I'm having trouble designing a circuit using an Op-Amp (741) to generate pulses.
The task given to me is:

> Design a pulse generator with a duty cycle that is adjustable from 0 to 100% and whose frequency can be set between 500Hz and 1KHz. Only DC supply may be used.

I found the following diagram:

[image]

Now, I know you can set the frequency by adjusting R2, but I'm unsure how to adjust the duty cycle (make R a potentiometer?). Also, what kind of values can be expected for the resistors and capacitor?

Thank you

Comment: That circuit won't work. (1) It uses a dual-voltage DC supply. (2) There is no duty-cycle adjust. Since this is homework we will guide you when you show your work so far. You need to do some more research.

Comment: That circuit is a square wave generator. varying R or R2 will adjust the frequency. As the cct stands there is no way of adjusting the mark to space ratio.

Comment: @Transistor Why won't the circuit work if the op-amp uses a dual voltage DC supply?

Comment: @Carl, the exercise is to generate pulses. That implies a signal switching between zero and Vcc. The diagram shows that the 741 will switch between +Vsat and -Vsat so I reckon that's a fail right there. Question says that "only DC supply may be used" so that also (vaguely) implies that a single-ended supply must be used. The lack of duty-cycle adjustment should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzMcCt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This topology will work.

OP1 is a non-inverting schmitt trigger. OP2 is an integrator. OP3 is configured as a comparator.

The output of OP1 is a square wave which drives integrator OP2 the output of which is a triangle wave. OP3 compares the triangle wave to a settable threshold to produce the variable frequency pulse width modulated waveform.

[image: Variable frequency PWM generator]

Answer (score 0):

THis will easily work with dual supply .

But use Pot for R to change frequency from 1k to 10K using fixed 1k R in series with 10k Pot and C=0.1uF

The  Positive feedback is simply equal R values from output to Mid-supply (V+ +V-)/2 = 0V in this case.

This changes the threshold of the Relaxation Oscillation just like CMOS Schmitt triggers with 50% Hysteresis for the sawtooth input voltage on the Vin- RC side. to switch outputs.

The  negative feedback R self biases the cap to cross the upper and lower Vin+ threshold switched bu the output.

[Interactive Falstad Simulation here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000001625%207.010541234668786%2063%2010%2050%0Aa%20304%20368%20432%20368%208%2010%202%201000000%207.354538784504767%203.99983226367695%20100000%0Aw%20304%20352%20304%20304%200%0Ar%20304%20304%20432%20304%200%205860%0Aw%20432%20304%20432%20368%200%0Aw%20432%20368%20432%20432%200%0Ar%20432%20432%20304%20432%200%2050000%0Aw%20304%20384%20304%20432%202%0Ar%20304%20432%20208%20432%200%20100000%0Ag%20208%20432%20208%20464%200%0Ac%20304%20304%20208%20304%200%201.0000000000000001e-7%207.354538784504767%0Ag%20208%20304%20208%20336%200%0A211%20432%20368%20512%20368%200%201%208000%201%0Ar%20304%20384%20208%20384%200%20100000%0AR%20208%20384%20176%20384%200%200%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0A403%20160%20224%20288%20288%200%209_16_0_4354_10_0.00625_0_2_9_3%0Ax%20379%20253%20590%20256%204%2012%20Single%5Cssupply%5Cs12V%5Cs,%5CsVin%5Cp%5Csbiased%5Csto%5CsV%5Cp/2%0Ax%20440%20417%20554%20420%204%208%20Outputs%5Csmay%5Csnot%5Csreach%5Cssupply%5Csrails%0Ax%20486%20490%20539%20493%204%208%20T.%5CsStewart%5CsEE75%0Ao%209%2016%200%204353%2010%200.003125%200%202%209%203%0Ao%2011%2016%200%204362%2020%200.00009765625%201%201%0A38%202%200%201000%2010000%20Resistance%0A)

[image]

Your design adjusts the duty cycle.

This design rises 50% duty cycle and adjusts frequency by  RC=T rise time approx. 50% vs T@ 63%. R is shown as a fixed R but has a soft slider on right to adjust from slider option 1k to 10k. OK?

**I also used a single supply, so I used Pull-up/down to get V+/2 with equal R equivalent values.** I set Vout to only swing 2 to 10V from Vcc=12V due to some Saturation values of the driver . just approx.  OK?

For a dual supply use equal R's and remove pullup R to V+.